# looping through index value in java component JList?

Tags: java, loops

I am reading a JList named: class_list 
and  class_list.isSelectedIndex(n); where n=0,1,2,3,4 
and when I am executing the code and selecting any option from the jlist I am getting the same output when n==1 and when n==4 I am always getting the Joption and "Anita sharma " as output.

This is my code

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 4; n++) { // n is index value from 0-4
    class_list.isSelectedIndex(n);
    if (n == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        "Choose Any Class to Know the name of  \n their Resppective Class Teacher");
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        show_name.setText("Purnima Singh");
    } // if n=1 1st list selected
    if (n == 2) {
        show_name.setText("Suruchi Oberoi");
    }
    if (n == 3) {
        show_name.setText("Manjula");
    }
    if (n == 4) {
        show_name.setText("Anita Misra");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere in code you are setting text as "Anita sharma"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. With your code it for loop will iterate through 0-4 and change text accordingly. However only last (i==4) execution is visible as it next iteration overrides previous changes.

Below is effective code corresponding to for loop above:

```
   show_name.setText("Anita Misra");
```

Comment: but i am always getting the same output "Anita sharma " and JOptionPane

Comment: for n == 1 , show_name.setText("Purnima Singh"); will get executed . then for n == 2, show_name.setText("Suruchi Oberoi");.             then for n == 3, show_name.setText("Manjula");
and @last for n == 4 show_name.setText("Anita Misra");                        And n==4 being the last condition it's changes are visible barring earlier ones.

Comment: See the image below what i am getting as output 
[click here to see image](http://s24.postimg.org/6luk0czid/Screenshot_from_2014_02_13_12_13_35.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well thats a very inefficient code, there is no need of any loop. Try this:

```
private void class_listMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

String[] teachers={"Purnima Singh","Suruchi Oberoi","Manjula","Anita Misra"};

int selection=class_list.getSelectedIndex();

if(selection>0&&selection<=4) { show_name.setText(teachers[selection-1]); } 
   else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose Any Class to Know the name of  \n their Respective Class Teacher");
        }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the code in action http://s29.postimg.org/vwl72sv0l/Untitled.jpg

Explaination:
We add the code to MouseClicked Action whenever the user clicks on list,  `class_list.getSelectedIndex()` gets the INDEX of the element that is selected. Remember the indices are starting from zero but in our list the first element is the Heading "Class Name" So we subtract 1 from the `selection` variable. 
Mission Accomplished.That's it.

You should refer to javadoc when in doubt.

---

Your code corrected:

```
int selection=0;
for (int n = 0; n <= 4; n++) { // n is index value from 0-4
    if(class_list.isSelectedIndex(n)==true) { selection=n; }
                             }
if (selection == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "Choose Any Class to Know the name of  \n their Resppective Class Teacher");
}
if (selection == 1) {
    show_name.setText("Purnima Singh");
} // if n=1 1st list selected
if (selection == 2) {
    show_name.setText("Suruchi Oberoi");
}
if (selection == 3) {
    show_name.setText("Manjula");
}
if (selection == 4) {
    show_name.setText("Anita Misra");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the code something like this: In any case you can add any case in this approach:

```
switch (n) {
    case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Choose Any Class to Know the name of  \n their Resppective Class Teacher");
        break;
    case 1:
        show_name.setText("Purnima Singh");
        break;
    case 2:
        show_name.setText("Suruchi Oberoi");
        break;
    case 3:
        show_name.setText("Manjula");
        break;
    case 4:
        show_name.setText("Anita Misra");
        break;
}
```

And if you will the same operation in many values of `n` you can change the structure as following:

```
 case 0:
 case 5: Do your operation for `0` and `5` cases; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping when you want to get the value? I'm assuming the code you have is in a `ListSelectionListener`. Just use

- [`public E getSelectedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue%28%29) - Returns the value for the smallest selected cell index; the selected value when only a single item is selected in the list. When multiple items are selected, it is simply the value for the smallest selected index. Returns null if there is no selection.

instead of `getSelectedIndex()`

```
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[] nameList = {"Lebron", "James", "Kobe", "Bryant", "Michael", "Jordan"};
                final JList<String> list = new JList<>(nameList);
                list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
                            String name = (String) list.getSelectedValue();
                            System.out.println(name);
                        }
                    }
                });
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, list, "names", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```